# How can i export this Powershell export to a file

Tags: parsing, powershell

Hello again and thanks for the great help so far,

i have the following code and want to write the results into a textfile.

```
for($i = 2; $i -lt $elements.length; $i += 1) { # iterate over the length of $elements (2...n) excluding the header (0,1)
        $line += "|$($elements[$i])" -replace "\^(\((?:'\d+',?)+\))\^",'$1'
        $j += 1
        if($j -eq 3) { 


            write-host $header$line 

            $line = ""
            $j = 0
        }
```

The Line

```
 write-host $header$line
```

gives me some rows in the PowerShell Line, but I want to append it to a textfile.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pipe it to Out-File

```
$header | Out-File -Filepath c:\myfile.txt 

$line | Out-File -Filepath c:\myfile.txt  -Append
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but je just appends the last row. how can i tell him to write all lines to the file?

Comment: Could use `-Append` with `Out-File`. Might be better to build a string array that later gets appended. Would cut down on all the file calls if you have a lot of data